# unable to find location application crashes

Tags: android, location

I am trying to detect user location in one small android app.

The application was running previously.

But now when i run my application it just crashes.

Here is my code.

```
private void getUserLocation() {

    location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (location_manager != null) {
        provider = location_manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = location_manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                Map.MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                Map.MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lang = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.kamani.nearby/com.project.kamani.nearby.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(10925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(10925):    at com.project.kamani.nearby.Map.getUserLocation(Map.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(10925):    at com.project.kamani.nearby.Map.onCreate(Map.java:75)
```

Here as per my interpretation it says that the error is at line 75 in my code.

So as viewed at line 75 i just called the above function `getUserLocation()`

I am unable to understand why it throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Actually error is at Map.java: line no.185

Comment: Have u declared this class in `AndroidManifest.xml` file??

Comment: post all your class Activity/Service

Comment: @Nizam at line 185 i am getting the latitude and longitude which is shown in above function.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i already tried it using that tutorial but it gives much more code which is not necessary.Thanks for your support.

Comment: Do Code Less that u have Need

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Ya that is what i have done here try to look at above do you find any bug?In tutorial we are setting the provider and then setting the services and many more while in above case i done it using getBestProvider().I am not comparing but i mean to say is there any problem in above solution?Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem may be because of a null location. Verify it is not null before using it. (as `location.getLatitude()` here).

Try following code.

```
private void getUserLocation() {

location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (location_manager != null) {

   List<String > provider=location_manager .getAllProviders();
            Location location = null;
            for(int i=0;i<provider.size();i++){
                 location=location_manager .getLastKnownLocation(provider.get(i));
                 if(location!=null){
                          location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider.get(i),
                                                    Map.MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                                    Map.MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                       break;
                      }
            }


if(location!=null){
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lang = location.getLongitude();
}else{
  // here you can initialize manually if you wish
}
}
}
```

Comment: Ya you are right now if location remains null how can i find out location?I think there is no bug in code? am i right?

Comment: LocationManager have 3 providers for getting current location. Here I'm looping through all of them to find out location. Still if the location is null, check out the settings of your android device.

Comment: What can be the settings in device?

Comment: Inside settings, there is a section for Location. Check whether its enabled or not.

Comment: it is enabled.Your solution is correct but i think we are missing something?

Comment: Just now my friend called me saying 'location is null for him for all the providers'. It was working until this afternoon. Don't know why sometimes..

Comment: what you want to say i am unable to understand?finally its working.i made no chage.Don't know why?

Comment: that's what I said. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. So 'null' check is the only way to avoid crash.

Answer (score 1):

getLastKnownLocation return null if it doesn't have data for the selected provider. So if it doesn't have a last know location, lat and long will always be null because the location is set in the listener, it's asynchronous, so you need to set lat and long in onLocationChanged.

You should also move to the LocationClient in google play services http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html